# Disk is Likely to Fail Soon (HDD) _22.04

Tags: hard-drive, backup, 22.04

Got a "Disk is Likely to Fail Soon" warning for my HDD and ran smartctl with the output as follow:

```
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   051   051   051    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 5942
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   194   191   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       1275
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   067   067   000    Old_age   Always       -       33978
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       4122
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       4024
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       413
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   199   199   000    Old_age   Always       -       916
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   187   187   000    Old_age   Always       -       41575
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   106   102   000    Old_age   Always       -       37
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       4
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
```

Two questions from regarding the output:

Is there any software in the apt repository which can be used to scan/check whether any of the files in the HDD are affected(broken) from this warning.

I'm using this internal HDD in my laptop for manual backups(distro and all app are running on a separated SSD), hence, is this still usable or should I backup everything to an external drive till i have a replacement?

Kindly advise

Comment: You can run `fsck` on this disk. You need a backup for that disk, if you don't have other backups yet.

Comment: If this is your backup drive then effectively you don’t have a reliable backup. I would use it as little as possible until you can get a replacement. In fact it might be best to remove it now. That would probably give a better chance of using it for recovery should the worst happen to the rest of your system

Comment: @Pilot6, just ran fsck with the follow ouput: `NewHDD: clean, 59913/61054976 files, 5952005/244190646 blocks`, hence, reckon the files are safe for now right?

Comment: The files are safe, that's correct. But it can change anytime.

Comment: `fsck` only checks for errors in the filesystem. It cannot tell you if your files are already corrupted or not. Only separate file checksum can do this for you. Or when using a filesystem which automatically does file checksum, like the btrfs filesystem.

Comment: @Pilot6, thank you, will backup the files to an ext drive. Last question, will there be any adverse affect to keeping the HDD mount till the replacement arrives or should i dismount it asap? Files are manually backup and it is solely for files not system backup.

Comment: I don't think in makes any difference, if you don't use the disk.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools  *I'm not aware of any software that will tell you what file(s) are most at risk/most-impacted; but drives can vary in their response to problems; cheaper drives with longer warranty give less than enterprise/faster drives with shorter warranty where details are easier to find somewhat*

Comment: And for backups i advise u to use the btrfs filesystem with raid1. You can mix drives ( no need for identical drives ), and you will have data integritiy checks on the fly with autocorrection and almost infinite rollbacks